# What is the recommend function for Ridge regression

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, glmnet

I am asking which functions are more trusted to use because they are giving different results each time when compared with textbook calculation.

I am working with ridge regression in R. I have three functions to use which are `glmnet` or `lm.ridge` or textbook calculation.

I can make the `glmnet` results as textbook calculation results.

```
p.tmp <- 5
n.tmp <- 30

set.seed(123)
X=scale(matrix(rnorm(n.tmp*p.tmp),ncol = p.tmp))
Y=scale(rnorm(n.tmp))

set.seed(123) 
ridge.fit.cv <- cv.glmnet(X, Y, alpha = 0, standardize = FALSE, intercept = FALSE)
ridge.fit.lambda <- ridge.fit.cv$lambda.1se
ridge_mod <- coef(glmnet(X, Y, alpha=0, standardize = FALSE,   lambda = ridge.fit.lambda) )[-1]
###############################
ridge.coef.DEF = solve(t(X) %*% X + n.tmp* ridge.fit.lambda * diag(p.tmp)) %*% t(X) %*% Y
cbind(glmnet=c(ridge_mod),textbook=c(ridge.coef.DEF), lm.ridge=c(coef( lm.ridge(Y~X - 1, lambda=ridge.fit.lambda))))
```

The results as follows

```
          glmnet      textbook     lm.ridge
X1  3.040157e-04  3.092039e-04  0.009102455
X2  9.805261e-04  9.972422e-04  0.028596273
X3  1.514714e-04  1.540631e-04  0.004855324
X4  1.721871e-04  1.751177e-04  0.004789519
X5 -4.282657e-05 -4.355457e-05 -0.001143931
```

Or I can also make `lm.ridge` results as textbook calculation as giving below

```
set.seed(123) 
ridge.fit.cv <- cv.glmnet(X, Y, alpha = 0, standardize = FALSE, intercept = FALSE)
ridge.fit.lambda <- ridge.fit.cv$lambda.1se
ridge_mod <- coef(glmnet(X, Y, alpha=0, standardize = FALSE,   lambda = ridge.fit.lambda) )[-1]
###############################
ridge.coef.DEF = solve(t(X) %*% X + ridge.fit.lambda * diag(p.tmp)) %*% t(X) %*% Y
cbind(glmnet=c(ridge_mod),textbook=c(ridge.coef.DEF), lm.ridge=c(coef( lm.ridge(Y~X - 1, lambda=ridge.fit.lambda*(30/29)))))
```

The results as

```
          glmnet     textbook     lm.ridge
X1  3.040157e-04  0.008815056  0.008815056
X2  9.805261e-04  0.027715213  0.027715213
X3  1.514714e-04  0.004692398  0.004692398
X4  1.721871e-04  0.004649196  0.004649196
X5 -4.282657e-05 -0.001112091 -0.001112091
```

****My question is which method I should believe because as you notice the results are different.****

Should I make the text calculation as `glmnet` or as `lm.ridge`?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but it seems the results are quite similar, that is, proportional. Computing the ratios of the coefficients in your example looks like the results are equivalent taking in account the computing error.
Saying that, the ratios of the ```glmnet``` are exactly the same as the textbook, so this could be your answer?

Comment: If you look at the second results, 'glmnet' and textbook results are different. So still not sure which function to use.

Comment: They are proportional. So are the ```glmnet``` and ```lm.ridge```. As far as I can see they are the same for any practical purpose.

Comment: Kindly clarify this more, because I do not get you.

Comment: If you multiply the results of the ```gomnet```with (arround) 30, you get the tesults of ```lm.ridge```. The relationships between the coefficients of the model are the same in both. If you use them for prediction the same predictied values can be expected, so when using the results of the model it won't matter which procedure you use.

Comment: And by the way it's statistics, not atomic watch. In statistics you are bound to have quite big errors, so the differences you see here, don't matter that much...